# ASP.NET Forms Authentication via Querystring

Tags: asp.net, query-string, membership

I currently have an ASP.NET 3.5 SP1 running on IIS 7. I have enabled forms authentication using .NET Membership and setup some folders that are restricted according to roles I have created. For instance, if an anonymous visitor tries to access the file http://www.example.com/restricted/foo.txt, he/she will be redirected to a login page, as expected. So far so good.

What I would like to do is provide access to protected files by allowing visitors to specify their login credentials in a query string, something alone the lines of:

http://www.example.com/foo.txt?user=username&pass=pwd

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to write an http module that intercepts the request and authenticates the user based on the querystring.  However, just for the sake of completeness, I'd like to question whether it's a good idea to provide users their username and (in particular) password in plaintext.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, Joel. I've never written an http module before, but I will pursue that route and let you know how it works!

Comment: Incidentally, I figured someone would raise the question of security :-) I don't really intend to share this functionality with most users of the site. The goal is to simply allow a widget on my site to access the file (it takes a URL as input), and the user role I'm specifying for this widget is very restrictive, so no crucial data is exposed. I figured this would at least provide some degree of security to the files used by the widget, though I admit that it certainly isn't foolproof.

Comment: I know this is an old post but allow me to point that this can also bedone securely by encrypting a concat of the username with the password + a timestamp and for example an IP and then decrypt and parse on the receiving end. You can also use a changing salt to tighten it further up.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily create a download page that would authenticate the user and then forward them to the requested file. Something like navigating to Download.aspx?user=username&pass=pwd&file=foo.txt.

**This however is NOT recommended.** You should never require users to pass login information via a URL.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, Dan! See my comment above regarding security. My real dilemma is that I need to pass a URL that my widget can access (it would be ideal to pass a local path, but since it's a 3rd party widget, it has to be a web url).

Answer (score 0):

A secondary answer based on comments you've made to other questions is that you could simply put your download page in a directory.  The subfolder could have a web.config that allows unauthenticated users access to the contents within :-)

something like:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <authorization>
         <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```